# JS acceleration and deceleration

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple level based platformer for a game-making comp at my school.

When the user holds the right arrow key the character starts gradually moving right, and speeds up until it reaches a max speed. It keeps travelling at that max speed, until the arrow key is released. When it is released, the character gradually slows down and stops.

I can make it speed up, but when the key is released, the character jumps forward and stops instantly, rather than slowing down then stopping.

Here's my code:

```
    var maxSpeed = 10; 
    var xForce = 0;
    var CharaXPos = 10;
    var CharaYPos = 200;

var draw = function() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    image(getImage("creatures/Winston"), CharaXPos, CharaYPos, 50, 50);
        if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT) {
            CharaXPos = CharaXPos + xForce;
            xForce = xForce + 0.25;
                if (xForce >= maxSpeed && keyIsPressed) {
                    xForce = maxSpeed;
                }
                }

        if (!keyIsPressed) {
                    while (xForce > 0) {
                        CharaXPos = CharaXPos + xForce;
                        xForce = xForce - xForce*0.25;
                    }}
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew about that decimal decreasing in value and never reaching zero, but some different saves got mixed up while I had two iterations of this code open on two different computers. (I no longer had access to one of the computers, so i had to use the one with the earlier save)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `while` loop to an `if` statement so that the force is decreased a little bit once per call to `draw()` instead of decreasing all the way to 0 in a single call to `draw()`.

Also, be careful about `xForce = xForce - xForce*0.25`, because that'll bring `xForce` closer and closer to 0 without ever quite getting there. Try just `xForce = xForce - 0.25` (the opposite of your acceleration code).